# Stop the search at the first match, in a folder of +900 folders PYTHON

Tags: python, directory, path, match, listdir

I have a folder (C: \ Users \ jrange14 \ Desktop \ Jobs), that inside there are more than 900 folders with the following format:

"Three numbers" + "_" + "the name of the job"

Example: 888_jtjdt

I want to do a search where the user only has to ask for a three digits input called JOB, the program will search on the entire folder and find the desired folder, with only the first 3 characters of the folder.

This is the Python code to obtain the path of that folder:

```
import os
import fnmatch

#Job to find
job = "888"

#This is the folder where all the "jobs" are
eng_path=r"C:\Users\jrange14\Desktop\Jobs"

#Define the path in which we will work
os.chdir(eng_path)
path = os.getcwd()
print(path)

#Look in the directory
for dirs in os.listdir():

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(dirs, job+"*"):
        #print(dirs)
        job_name = dirs

job_path=eng_path+'\\'+job_name

print(job_path)
```

With this code, I can get 3 things,
The working directory:

```
C:\Users\jrange14\Desktop\Jobs
```

The full name of the desired folder:

```
888_jtjdt
```

And the sum of the previous two to get the full path of that folder:

```
C:\Users\jrange14\Desktop\Jobs\888_jtjdt
```

The PROBLEM is that this code takes a long time to obtain this answer because inside the folder there are many folders (more than 900) and match each one of them with the input.

From what I see my problem is here:

```
#Look in the directory
for dirs in os.listdir():

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(dirs, job+"*"):
        #print(dirs)
        job_name = dirs
```

With this `for` I see that it goes through the entire directory, looking for the match of our input. and even if the program finds the desired folder, it continues through the entire directory looking for another one

Due to the first three numbers of each job are different from each other, there is no need to keep looking for other possible matches.

What can I do to stop the program at the first match?

Comment: To exit from a loop there is the `break` statement. Also look at the `glob` module which may help to make the whole thing faster.

Comment: I have tried the `glob` module but seems that it works the same way

Answer (score 1):

The solution to make the program faster is to use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Using `os.listdir()` will take just about the same amount of time regardless of when the actual file is found, because it's not a generator, it doesn't generate each finding during each iteration, it lists *all* the files into memory first, *then* iterates through them.

Use [`path.py`](https://pypi.org/project/path.py/):

```
from path import Path

eng_path = r"C:\Users\jrange14\Desktop\Jobs"
d = Path(eng_path)
job = "888"

for dirs in d.dirs(f'{job}_*'):
    print(dirs)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
import os

#Job to find
job_number = "888_"

#This is the folder where all the "jobs" are
eng_path=r"C:\Users\jrange14\Desktop\Jobs"

#Look in the directory
job_name = None
for entry in os.listdir(eng_path):
    if entry.startswith(job_number):
        job_name = entry
        break
if job_name is None:
    print("Job number not found")
else:
    job_path=eng_path+'\\'+job_name
    print(job_path)
```

Comment: Hi Balaji, unfortunately somehow the `break` statement is not working. And seems that it's still checking for all the folders, taking the same amount of time. I don't know why the `break' doesn't exit from the loop, seems that I missing something.

Comment: @JorgeRangel What makes you say that?

Comment: because it took the same amount of time to get the desired path

Comment: That's because of the way [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir) works. This part is from the doc `The list is in arbitrary order`

If you want, print the `entry` within the `for loop` and see for yourself. Once `888_` is found, the loop will break

Comment: if I print the `entry` within the `for` the program waits the same amount of time that took to find the desired folder, and then in one hit, it prints ALL the folders with the desired path at the end.

Comment: now, the code that I shared has up to 900 folders, but my real application has over ten thousand of folders on it. The "job's number" has a length of 10 characters (like 6500701364_xxxxxx), and when I ask for the job number, the program took 23 seconds to get the desired folder. My problem is that it always prints all the folders and at the end, it prints the desired folder

Comment: @JorgeRangel What you're looking to observe is the last printed `entry`. Did it start with `888_` ?

Comment: I tried the solution that @Sercan told me, and it works. When I put a 'break' at the end of the `IF` inside the `FOR`, it breaks when it found a match. But I have the following problem, my real application is a folder with more than ten thousand of folders, why it takes the same amount of time, even when I look for different job numbers?